# Make UbuntuStudio look like regular Ubuntu(I wanted the kernal not the desktop)

Tags: themes

I would like to make Ubuntu Studio 14.04 look like regular Ubuntu trusty 14.04 with the Unity desktop.

Please see this [screen shot of the default Ubuntu Studio desktop](http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/Ubuntu-Studio-13-10-Beta-2-Saucy-Salamander-Screenshot-Tour-386793-5.jpg) .

Comment: How it looks has very little to do with the kernel.

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't just install Ubuntu 14.04 instead of Ubuntu Studio then? You can just install `linux-image-lowlatency` to get the low latency kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You can install ubuntu DE with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^
```

Comment: There is a taskel job for Ubuntu-desktop?

Comment: @Seth Yes, but the caret is no longer strictly needed.